# Im trying to request information from an football api but Im having trouble with the responses

Tags: node.js, json, api

So Im trying to request information from the football-data.org api but Im having trouble because its returning black information i tried looking at the documentation but there's none for Nodejs

Here is my code

```
import express from 'express';
import 'dotenv/config';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';


const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static("public"));



app.get("/", function(req, res){
    
    fetch("https://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/PL/matches?status=SCHEDULED", {
        headers: {
            method: 'GET',
            'X-Auth-Token': process.env.API_KEY,
        },
  
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

    
});


app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server has started on port 3000");
});
```

when i run it i get this about 20 times just with different numbers

```
{
      id: 327024,
      season: [Object],
      utcDate: '2022-04-23T14:00:00Z',
      status: 'SCHEDULED',
      matchday: 34,
      stage: 'REGULAR_SEASON',
      group: null,
      lastUpdated: '2021-06-16T14:31:53Z',
      odds: [Object],
      score: [Object],
      homeTeam: [Object],
      awayTeam: [Object],
      referees: []
    },
```

i should get something like

the names off the teams playing and the other stuff not object

Comment: Look very carefully at the structure of the responses. You need to access a few more properties before you can get to the two you want.

Comment: `data` is an object with a single attribute `matches`. It's not clear where you got the idea that the root object specifically should have any attribute `hometeam` or `awayteam`. `data.matches[0].homeTeam`, perhaps? (Variable/function names are CaSe SeNsItIvE, fyi)

Comment: Using node has nothing to do with how you access data in the response. (This is the fundamental issue as indicated by previous comments.) The process will be the same in any language. You will just use JavaScript rather than some other language to do so. Therefore, if there are examples in other languages, you can use that as a template for conversion to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your API key is correct you just need to change your `competition` to `competitions` in your GET URL.

See a working link below that I was able to try on Postman after generating my API key.

```
https://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/PL/matches?status=SCHEDULED
```

Replace your current URL with this one and it should work (unless something is wrong with your API key).